# Add Amazon Affiliate links to Netlify CMS Hugo site - markup unsafe=true

Tags: iframe, markup, hugo, netlify-cms

I created the default Netlify CMS site with Hugo to test it out. The first test I wanted to do was to get Amazon Affiliate sites to work. With my actual site, I had to edit the config.toml file to include:

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

In order for the  tags to work.

However, with this newly deployed site, it's using the config.yml file. I tried to edit the file located here: theme-name/site/static/admin/config.yml . See the photo, below.

[image]

Nothing seems to work. However, in the preview pane, the ads show up without an issue.

[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path. I had to add this code:

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

to the [theme-name]/site/config.toml file.

[image]

There were at least two config.toml files in different paths. Also, there is a config.yml file. It was a matter of choosing the right path.